# How to convert a number to its correlating day of the week?

Tags: python, numbers, weekday

How do I convert a number to its correlating day of the week?

For example:

```
def string(hour_of_day, day_of_week, date) :
   print(f'{day_of_week} {date} at hour {hour_of_day}')
```

how can I re-write the 'day_of_week' part in `print` so that when I use the function:

```
string(12, 1, '2020/02/18')
```

How can I get `Tuesday 2020/02/18 at hour 12` instead of `1 2020/02/18 at hour 12`?

Comment: You wrote quite wrongly functionname and question - not very helpful for helpers.

Comment: You wrote the function in a way that you enter already `day_of_week`. so calling `string(12, 'Tuesday', '2020/02/18')` will do it. - But I am pretty sure this is not what you want.

Comment: So you asked the wrong question.

Comment: What you want to ask is actually: How can I get from the date the day of week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `calendar` module

If you have already the weekday number, do:

```
import calendar

day_of_week = 1
calendar.day_name[day_of_week]
## 'Tuesday'
```

The calendar module is always available in Python (it is belongs to the inbuilt standard modules).

So the dictionary `{0: "Monday", 1: "Tuesday", ...}` is already defined as `calendar.day_name`. So no need to define it yourself. Instead type `import calendar` and you have it available.

### Use `datetime` module to get weekday directly from the date

```
from datetime import datetime

def date2weekday(date):
    return datetime.strptime(date, "%Y/%m/%d").strftime('%A')

def myfunction(hour_of_day, date):
    return f"{date2weekday(date)} {date} at hour {hour_of_day}"

myfunction(12, '2020/02/18') 
## 'Tuesday 2020/02/18 at hour 12'
```

Comment: using the calendar import proved helpful. cheers @Gwang-Jin Kim

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary along the lines of

`daysdict = { 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Tuesday'}`  exetended for all the days

then access using `daysdict[1]`

Although your day 1 seems to be Tuesday!

It is possible to get the day directly from the date itself - something for you to check out.

Comment: 0 is monday 1 is tuesday etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strftime method from a datetime object:

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 21).strftime('%A %Y/%m/%d'))
```

It will give you this answer:

```
Friday 2022/10/21
```

To adapt it to your solution just do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def string(hour_of_day, date):
    print(f'{date.strftime('%A %Y/%m/%d')} at hour {hour_of_day}')

string(12, datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=21))
```

The good thing about this solution is that you don't need to know the day of the week of a date, Python already knows that, just ask him ;)

To know more about date formatting you can visit the [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) in the official Python site

Comment: I tried this but it just resulted in:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'